# UIAlertController actionsheet too slow to pop up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiactionsheet, uialertcontroller

I'm presenting an ActionSheet with `UIAlertController` when a tableView cell is selected.

My code is like this:

```
 UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Select Action"
                                                               message:nil
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
 [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Action 1"
                                          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                        handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) 
 {
        [self handleAction1Selected];
 }]];

 [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Action 2"
                                          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                        handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) 
 {
        [self handleAction2Selected];
 }]];

 [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Action 3"
                                          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                        handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action)
 {
        [self handleAction3Selected];
 }]];

 [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil]];

 [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This code is called in `[tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]` method,
however, there is always huge lag after I select a tableview cell until the ActionSheet actually pops up.

The lag ranges between 1 second to 10, sometimes even 20 seconds.

This is pretty simple code without much configuration, is there anything I'm doing wrong or it's just a bug for Apple?

Comment: I searched and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469268/delay-in-presenting-a-modal-view-controller).

Comment: You have to add the alert controller to your custom cell class rather then adding it in the  [tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] method